# SSIS - REST API for Freshdesk

Tags: c#, rest, api, ssis, freshdesk

I tried searching something here but nothing seems to fit my need.
I created an SSIS package that runs a report -> Attaches it to an email and send it to a bunch of people, many times (different recipients, different files).

Due to Zapier limitations I can't create a FreshDesk ticket with attachments and that is for me a must to have so I'm exploring FreshDesk API, but I'm no c# developer.
I found some examples online and now I'm trying to fit this code:
[FreshSamples C-Sharp Create Ticket with attachment](https://github.com/freshdesk/fresh-samples/blob/master/C-Sharp/CreateTicketWithCustomField.cs) into my existing code, hoping to pass all my variable as ticket fields '

```
    #region VSTA generated code
    enum ScriptResults
    {
        Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
        Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
    };
    #endregion


    public void Main()
    {

        // initialize StreamReader class for text file
        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(Dts.Variables["User::MHTMailPath"].Value.ToString());
        // Read the StreamReader To End and assign to local variable
        string StreamText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        // assign SSIS variable with value of StreamText local variable.
        this.Dts.Variables["User::HTMLMail"].Value = StreamText;

        // TODO: Add your code here
        MailMessage email = new MailMessage();



        if ((Dts.Variables["User::MHTEmail1"].Value.ToString() != null) && (Dts.Variables["User::MHTEmail1"].Value.ToString() != string.Empty))
        {
            email.To.Add(Dts.Variables["User::MHTEmail1"].Value.ToString());
        }
        if ((Dts.Variables["User::MHTEmail2"].Value.ToString() != null) && (Dts.Variables["User::MHTEmail2"].Value.ToString() != string.Empty))
        {
            email.To.Add(Dts.Variables["User::MHTEmail2"].Value.ToString());
        }
        if ((Dts.Variables["User::MHTEmail3"].Value.ToString() != null) && (Dts.Variables["User::MHTEmail3"].Value.ToString() != string.Empty))
        {
            email.To.Add(Dts.Variables["User::MHTEmail3"].Value.ToString());
        }
        if ((Dts.Variables["User::MHTEmail4"].Value.ToString() != null) && (Dts.Variables["User::MHTEmail4"].Value.ToString() != string.Empty))
        {
            email.To.Add(Dts.Variables["User::MHTEmail4"].Value.ToString());
        }

        //email.CC.Add(CCAddresses);
        email.From = new MailAddress("xxx@xxx.com");
        email.Subject = Dts.Variables["User::MHTCd"].Value.ToString() + " - " + Dts.Variables["User::MHTCustomerDS"].Value.ToString() + " R" + Dts.Variables["User::Period"].Value.ToString().Trim().Substring(Dts.Variables["User::Period"].Value.ToString().Trim().Length - 2, 2);
        email.IsBodyHtml = true;
        email.Body = Dts.Variables["User::HTMLMail"].Value.ToString(); 
        string reportFile = Dts.Variables["User::ReportFile"].Value.ToString();
        try
        {
            //For MHT file. Decode MHTML to HTML and embed in email body
            if (Path.GetExtension(reportFile) == ".mht")
            {
                var decodedHtml = new StringBuilder();
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(reportFile))
                {
                    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        var line = reader.ReadLine();
                        if (line != "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64") continue;

                        reader.ReadLine();
                        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != String.Empty)
                            if (line != null)
                                decodedHtml.Append(
                                    Encoding.UTF8.GetString(
                                        Convert.FromBase64String(line)));
                        break;
                    }
                }
                email.Body = email.Body + Environment.NewLine + decodedHtml.ToString();
                email.IsBodyHtml = true;
            }

            else
            {
                //Attach the file
                Attachment attachmentFile = new Attachment(reportFile);
                email.Attachments.Add(attachmentFile);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Dts.Events.FireError(0, "create email message", e.Message, String.Empty, 0);
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
        }

        //System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
        smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
        smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("xxx@xxx.com", "xxxxxxx");
        System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        try
        {
            smtpClient.Send(email);
            //email.Attachments.Dispose();
            //File.Delete(reportFile);
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Dts.Events.FireError(0, "smtp emailing", e.Message, String.Empty, 0);
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (email != null)
            {
                email.Dispose();
            }
            if (smtpClient != null)
            {
                //smtpClient.Dispose();
            }
        }
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }

}
```

but I'm losing my mind trying to get my reportFile to be correctly "taken" by FreshDesk sample which expects a file on the filesystem. Moreover, I will need to attach more that one file so I was wondering if any good samaritan would point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance

Ren

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be okay to call email.Attachments.Add() multiple times to add multiple attachments:

The key part is :

To turn an existing file into an attachment:

```
    Attachment attachmentFile = new Attachment(reportFile);
    email.Attachments.Add(attachmentFile);
```

To turn a string block into an attachment:

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
{
    writer.Write(reportFile);
    writer.Flush();
    stream.Position = 0;

    email.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(stream, "myreport-xyz.txt", "text/plain"));
}
```