# SSIS - SSRS Report grouping for email by table field

Tags: c#, sql-server, reporting-services, ssis

I am tasked to send different report files to my customers (I asked something different [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59093690/ssis-rest-api-for-freshdesk/59095163#59095163) but I bypassed it not using Freshdesk).

I have all my data inside a table, each customer has its own VAT id and a variable number of rows for the order.
I need to create an excel file for each VAT-Country combination and send all generated files for each VAT to a specific email address (extracted from an SSRS report called n times)

VAT1-IT.xlsx,VAT1-NL.xlsx,VAT1-EE.xlsx TO EMAIL 1

VAT2-EE.xlsx,VAT2-UK.xlsx TO EMAIL 2

VAT3-GR.xlsx TO EMAIL 3

So far I've been able to generate all the files in a specific folder but I'm stuck at taking the correct files and send them to the correct customer. I'm able to send a single attachment to a recipient (using a script task to send the email since I have variable email subjects and bodies.

What I thought could have been a good way to do this was to create two ForEach Loops: 
The parent will extract only VAT Numbers and the second one all the details (VAT-Country-Email Addresses); I figured that the second one would loop until the combinations for a VAT-Country would finish and then pass to another iteration, but evidently I'm wrong.

[image: SSIS Package flow]

Is there a way to achieve this? 
Could be generating all the files and then fetch them from the filesystem a better way to achieve this?

Comment: This sounds like you want Data-Driven Reports. There are many articles on how to achieve similar functionality if you're using Standard Edition.

Comment: Thanks, but as far as I know, Data-Driven Subscriptions can't send multiple report executions in a single email. Am I wrong? I'm on std edition btw so I would need to use something different, which I'm in part already doing

Comment: No, they can't; but if you want them all in a single email, then put then all in one report (using sub reports).

Comment: I think I may have misexplained something. The ssrs that generates the excel is just one. In the first foreach loop I iter all vat/country combinations passing them as parameters to the report.

Comment: You can by pass SSIS if you can use Data Driven subscriptions in SSRS. Works a treat and for multiple reports, combine them into one report as Larnu has suggested.

Comment: Shouldn't the first task write the VATs to a recordset (and thus be a dataflow task) that can be looped using the outer Foreach Loop Container? And shouldn't a "Send Email" task be inside that Foreach Loop Container?

Comment: @Harry, I don't have DDS otherwise I would have used them :)

Comment: @WolfgangKais Thanks for the suggestion, I'm getting VAT and Countries in the parent loop while getting all parameters in the child one. I'll try getting only VATs and moving the mail send task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to achieve this mostly thanks to @WolfgangKais who pointed me in the right direction.

The new SSIS is like that

[image]

ANd in the end I handled the sending of many attachments into one mail directly into the script task in c# (I'm no developer but i was able to find some examples ready to edit).

Thanks everyone for the suggestions.